# Open source FortiGate (Forti SSL VPN) client support in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, ssl

Does anyone work on adding support for open source FortiGate SSL VPN NetworkManager client to Ubuntu?

According to [this blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/lkundrak/2015/09/24/fortigate-ssl-vpn-support-added-to-networkmanager/) there is initial support for open source FortiGate client.

Frontend: network-manager-fortisslvpn.
Backend: openfortivpn.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic), you can connect with the regular network manager by simply installing the package `network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome`. Find it in *Software* or do:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome
```

(This will also install dependencies openfortivpn and network-manager-fortisslvpn.)

Then you can click `Edit connections` in network manager (right-click the Wi-Fi icon), **+** to add a new one, select type `Fortinet SSLVPN` under the `VPN` heading. Give it a name, then under `Gateway` put in the IP address (and optionally port separated by colon, e.g., `11.22.33.44:44443`) and username/password. Note that you may have to click the little symbol in the password field to select who has access to the password before you're allowed to type anything in that text field.

Save and right-click the Wi-Fi icon again, click VPN and pick the name you chose.

#### Gateway certificate validation

If it doesn't work, that may be because you need to trust a certificate. If you have the certificate fingerprint, you can edit your connection and add it under `Advanced→Trusted certificate`. If you don't know your certificate, [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/922767/104546) explains how to find it from the terminal.

```
$ journalctl -xe | grep "NetworkManager.*ERROR"

ERROR:  Gateway certificate validation failed, and the certificate digest in not in the local whitelist. If you trust it, rerun with:
ERROR:      --trusted-cert 1234af...
ERROR:  or add this line to your config file:
ERROR:      trusted-cert = 1234af...
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I installed `network-manager-fortisslvpn` and `openfortivpn`, but nothing new shows up in the Network Manager "Add connection" dialog. (On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with GNOME Shell 3.18.5)

Comment: @moi did you restart NetworkManager with `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` after installing these packages?

Comment: Don't forget to install ´´´network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome´´´